how to fix ruff error on module level docstring between from future and normal imports
Many of my Python files start with a future import and a module level docstring:
from __future__ import annotations

"""
module level docstring
"""

from datetime import datetime as DateTime

print(DateTime.today())

The from __future__ import has to be at the top of the file, and although it can come after a module level docstring, I have some tooling that assumes that import is on the first non-comment/non-empty line. I also want to have my module level docstring close to the top, and not below a, potentially long, list of imports.
The above tests fine when using flake8 (which I use from tox).
I started looking into using ruff instead of flake8, but when I run ruff check on such a file I get:
test.py:8:1: E402 Module level import not at top of file
   |
 6 | """
 7 |
 8 | from datetime import datetime as DateTime
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ E402
 9 |
10 | print(DateTime.today())
   |

Found 1 error.

When I remove the from future import, or* remove the docstring, or move the docstring before the future import (or below all the imports), the E402 error disappears.
How can I correct ruff behaviour, so I can keep the order of the special from future import, the module docstring, and the normal imports, without suppressing any real E402 errors (i.e. that follow some actual code and not a docstring)?

I know I can add  # NOQA after each of the normal module level imports, but with several hundred files in the 200+ packages I maintain, that is not a route I prefer to take. I can update my tooling to handle non-top-of-file from __future__ imports, but I don't really look forward to hide those specific imports below a (longish) module docstring, especially since there might be breaking changes in the future.

the docstring should be at the very top -- above all imports (including __future__ imports)
otherwise it does not function and is just a haphazard string at the module level
$ cat t.py
"""docstring"""
import os
$ python3 -i t.py
>>> print(__doc__)
docstring

$ cat t2.py
import os
"""docstring"""
$ python3 -i t2.py
>>> print(__doc__)
None

the linter error is telling you indirectly that your docstring is useless (by telling you that your imports are not at the top -- since they're after a "statement") and you must put it at the top
